# Changing the window title bar on an Android Application

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried to add a differnt layout for my window title bar, but in the same page I already have an action bar, and when I run my application I receive this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stampp/com.example.stampp.UI.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

And here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab alleTab = actionBar.newTab();
    alleListTabListener = new TabListener<AlleFragment>(this, R.id.container, AlleFragment.class);
    alleTab.setText("Alle").setContentDescription("Alle page").setTabListener(alleListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(alleTab);

    Tab favoriteTab = actionBar.newTab();
    favoriteListTabListener = new TabListener<FavoriteFragment>(this, R.id.container, FavoriteFragment.class);
    favoriteTab.setText("Favorite").setContentDescription("Favorite page").setTabListener(favoriteListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(favoriteTab);

    Tab umbegungTab = actionBar.newTab();
    umbegunfListTabListener = new TabListener<UmbegungFragment>(this, R.id.container, UmbegungFragment.class);
    umbegungTab.setText("Umbegung").setContentDescription("Umbegung page").setTabListener(umbegunfListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(umbegungTab);

}
```

Here is my window_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/menu_background">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/windowTitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    android:text="@string/shouts"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The error is thrown when I tried to create my action bar.
Can someone tell me how can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**
Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.stampp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.stampp.UI.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/shouts"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Include manifest code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set `Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` once, `setFeatureInt` can't be called again. A call to it will boil down to a requestFeature() call in the Window implementation, that method tests for FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE and throws the Exception if it is set.

Comment: I modified the code. I don't have any exception now,b ut the action bar is not changed